# Duplicate key error when performing update Express Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a field called mail as unique in MongoDB.

I'm trying to update the user but it happens that if I don't change the mail field it tells me it's a duplicate. I need it not to be necessary to always change the email because sometimes they just want to change another field.

This is my model:

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";

const UserSchema = Schema (
  {
    username: {
        type: String,
        maxlength:50,
        required: [true, 'El Nombre de Usuario es obligatorio'],
        unique: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        maxlength:50,
        required: [true, 'El Nombre es obligatorio']
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        maxlength:50,
        required: [true, 'El Apellido es obligatorio']
    },
    mail: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'El Correo es obligatorio'],
        unique: true
    },   
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'La Contraseña es obligatorio']
    },
    picture:{
        path: {
            type: String
        },
        originalName: {
            type: String
        }
        
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ['ADMIN_ROLE', 'USER_ROLE', 'SUPER_ROLE', 'SELLER_ROLE', 'WAREHOUSE_ROLE', 'WAREHOUSE_ASSISTANT_ROLE', 'SALES_ROLE', 'PURCHASES_ROLE','CASH_ROLE'] 
    },
    status: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },
    createdBy:{
        uid : { type: String, required: true },
        username:{ type: String, required: true }
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
  }  
);

module.exports = model('Users', UserSchema);
```

This is my function where I update but it returns the error of duplicate key in mail.

```
const updateUser = async (req, res = response) => {

    let id = req.params.id;

    let { _id, password,  ...data } = req.body;

    if ( password ) {

        let salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(15);
        resto.password = bcrypt.hashSync( password, salt );   
    }

    let lastModificationByUser = {
        uid: req.uid,
        username: req.user.username,
        comments: data.comments
    };

    let user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate( id,
        {
            $set: data, 
            $push: { 
                'lastModificationBy': {
                  $each: [lastModificationByUser],
                  $slice: -5 
                }
            }
        },{ new: true }
    );

    res.json({
        user
    })
}
```

But I get the following error:

[image: error image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Understand unique

1. if you create a user with a unique email address and then update their email address to a non-unique value (same email address), you'll get the dup key error.
2. if you insert a user with the email address empty, and you try to create another user with the email address empty, you will also get the dup error.

##### In your case

Remove the `mail` field from your `data` object, unless you are updating the user with a new unique email address.

##### DO NOT TRUST ANYTHING SUBMITTED CLIENT SIDE

```
let { _id, password,  ...data } = req.body;
```

Destructuring and then updating the `data` field directly to the model **is not safe**. (e.g. even if your form does not contain the password field)

For example, I can send a post request with `curl` or `postman` with the `password` field, and you will be updating the password too without knowing.

##### What you should do

```
const { name, lastname, picture } = data;

const update = { name, lastname, picture }

let user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate( id, update );
```

PS: this is just an example, though in your codes you already conditionally check your password.

Comment: Thanks friend, but what happens when you want to modify the email and I removed it from the request? This situation seems quite strange to me since I have the problem with "mail" but with "username" although I also require it as the only one there is no problem.

Comment: you use "unique" only in situations where it's required, and truly unique, like username. If email is removable, then don't set it as unique. In all my use cases, I rarely use `unique`, I always do checks before i insert/modify unique values instead of waiting for MongoDB to throw the error.